# How to locate the ticks to center of grid when plotting heatmap with seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I drew the heatmap with seaborn package and I want tick numbers to be located at the center between grids. What should I do to shift the ticks?

Also, I think space between the first plot and the second plot is too narrow while the space between the second plot and colorbar is too wide. What should I do to adjust the space between each axes?

The below is my code for plotting and I attach the resulting plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
fig, axs=plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(24, 10), gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[4,4,0.3]))
df1=pd.DataFrame(main_pmatrix)
df2=pd.DataFrame(after_pmatrix)
g1=sns.heatmap(df1, cmap='hot', ax=axs[0], cbar=False, vmin=0.9, vmax=1.8)
g2=sns.heatmap(df2, cmap='hot', ax=axs[1], cbar=False, vmin=0.9, vmax=1.8)
g1.set_xticks(range(21))
g1.set_xticklabels(['1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5','1.6','1.7','1.8','1.9','2.0','2.1','2.2','2.3','2.4','2.5','2.6','2.7','2.8','2.9','3.0'])
g2.set_xticks(range(21))
g2.set_xticklabels(['1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5','1.6','1.7','1.8','1.9','2.0','2.1','2.2','2.3','2.4','2.5','2.6','2.7','2.8','2.9','3.0'])
g1.set_yticks(range(11))
g1.set_yticklabels(['0.5','0.6','0.7','0.8','0.9','1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5'])
g1.set_xlabel("Fractal dimension, $d_f$", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
g1.set_ylabel("$b-$value", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
g2.set_yticks(range(11))
g2.set_yticklabels(['0.5','0.6','0.7','0.8','0.9','1.0','1.1','1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5'])
g2.set_xlabel("Fractal dimension, $d_f$", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
g2.set_ylabel("$b-$value", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
plt.colorbar(axs[1].collections[0], cax=axs[2])
plt.xlabel("$p$", fontsize=20, labelpad=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xticklabels=` and `yticklabels=` parameters of [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to set the desired tick labels at the correct positions. That way, the `set_xticks` etc. aren't needed. The vertical space between the subplots can be adjusted via the [`wspace` of the `gridspec_kw`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html).

Also note that it isn't needed to convert the matrices to a pandas dataframe, as seaborn will just convert the dataframe back to a 2D numpy array.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

main_pmatrix = np.random.uniform(1.2, 1.8, (11, 21))
after_pmatrix = np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.5, (11, 21))
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(24, 10), gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[4, 4, 0.3], wspace=0.2))
xticklabels = [f'{i:.1f}' for i in np.arange(1, 3.001, 0.1)]
yticklabels = [f'{i:.1f}' for i in np.arange(0.5, 1.501, 0.1)]
sns.heatmap(main_pmatrix, cmap='hot', ax=ax1, cbar=False, vmin=0.9, vmax=1.8,
            xticklabels=xticklabels, yticklabels=yticklabels)
sns.heatmap(after_pmatrix, cmap='hot', ax=ax2, cbar=False, vmin=0.9, vmax=1.8,
            xticklabels=xticklabels, yticklabels=yticklabels)

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_xlabel("Fractal dimension, $d_f$", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
    ax.set_ylabel("$b-$value", fontsize=25, labelpad=10)
ax1.set_title('Main p-matrix', fontsize=28)
ax2.set_title('After p-matrix', fontsize=28)
plt.colorbar(ax2.collections[0], cax=ax3)
ax3.set_xlabel("$p$", fontsize=20, labelpad=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]